# Ionic push notifications custom sound are not playing on Android Oreo and above versions

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, phonegap

As per Ionic documentation of push plugin, I created Channel for android O and above version.
Refer link:-

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

I actually wanna play custom sound when push notification received and its already working on Android 7(Nougat) and below versions, but I am getting issues on Android Oreo and above versions, push notifications are receiving, but not custom sounds are not playing. I referred lots of links to resolve this issue, but nothing to work.

Refer links:-

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2017

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2446

In mostly suggested solutions they suggested to add "sound" parameter in createChannel method like this:-

```
this.push.createChannel({
id: "testchannel7",
description: "asdf",
sound: 'pulse',
// The importance property goes from 1 = Lowest, 2 = Low, 3 = Normal, 4 = High and 5 = Highest.
importance: 4,
vibration: true
}).then(() => console.log('Channel created'));
```

But I am getting

**Typescript error :- Typescript Error
Argument of type '{ id: string; description: string; importance: 3; sound: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Channel'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'sound' does not exist in type 'Channel'.**

Even I stored my sound.mp3 files in following position:-
platforms/android/app/src/main/res/raw

In my payload sound parameter is already added without extension such as :-

```
{
...,
...,
sound: soundname,
...
}
```

My ionic environment configuration:-

**Ionic:**

**ionic (Ionic CLI)**  : 4.5.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)

**Ionic Framework**    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

**@ionic/app-scripts** : 3.1.6

**Cordova:**

**cordova (Cordova CLI)** : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)

**Cordova Platforms**     : android 7.1.4

**Cordova Plugins**       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.1

**Push Plugin Version:-**

phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"

Please help me to solve this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you able to solve this problem? Because I am looking for the same :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and update the @ionic-native/push to 4.20.0

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/push@4.20.0
```

worked for me .

Hope this help you

Comment: Please share your phonegap-plugin-push version

Comment: Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.5.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:
   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, browser 5.0.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 20 other plugins)

Comment: @RAJBABAR did u find any solution to this. I am also facing the same issue.